# VirtueMart 2 custom checkout steps

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I need to change the way VirtueMart performs the checkout by default. By default it goes like this:

1) cart page with login/registration, address & stuff, item list
2) confirm the order

What I need:

1) only the item list
2) login/registration, address & stuff
And preferrably no confirm page, instant check out after filling the form.

What's the best/easiest way to make it?

Answer (score -1):

With VM 2.0, these are all configurable options in the Administration Control Panel for Virtuemart.  As is the case with most of the VM config stuff, it's not always particularly intuitive, but the newer version is vastly better than the older version.

Spend some time reviewing the VM Configuration and Shop tabs to see how you can get it behaving how you'd like.  It appears to me that there is nothing on your list that can't be configured there.

Comment: I've actually crawled it many times searching for a solution. But it's not very rich. Maybe there are some hidden "secret" levels of configuration pages? %) That are not visible by default...